# Laravel How to store a variable into database and update it on every click

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have laravel blog, i have implement Add to favorite option using Vue.js and it's works very well. Now i want to implement like post (every user can like post more times), it's just like medium claps, i already have the clap button and it works, on every click the $likeCounter variable get updated and on hold also, the problem is how can i insert that variable ($likeCounter) into database (using javascript, vuejs ...)? The likes table has this columns
    user_id, post_id, likes_count
**user_id** & **post_id** (pivot) inserted using vue.js

in my controller i have this method to attach user_id and post_id

```
public function like(Post $post)
{
    Auth::user()->likes()->attach($post->id);

    return back();
}
```

in User model i have this method to get all liked posts for the authenticated user

```
/**
 * Get all of liked posts for the user.
 */
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'likes', 'user_id', 'post_id')->withTimeStamps();
}
```

in Post Model i have this method

```
/**
 * Determine whether a post has been liked by a user.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function liked()
{
    return (bool) Like::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                        ->where('post_id', $this->id)
                        ->first();
}

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Like');
}
```

in Like.vue

```
methods: {
        like(post) {
            axios.post('/like/'+post)
                .then(response => this.isLiked = true)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        },
```

I use some javascript to update a variable on every click until the current user rich the max which is 50 claps for every authenticated user

```
function updateNumberOfClaps() {
    numberOfClaps < 50 ? numberOfClaps++ : null
    clapCount.innerHTML = "+" + numberOfClaps
    clapTotalCount.innerHTML = initialNumberOfClaps + numberOfClaps
  }
```

and it works well (attached the new like with user_id and post_id), if the same user click again on the same post a new like will be attached in database with same user_id and the same post_id.
the issue is how can i store a variable counter in likes_count column and update it on every click, so instead of attached same post with same user again and again, i want to store a variable of how many the user like this post.
I hope this is clear

Comment: Where is the issue, frontend or backend?

Comment: @Tpojka backend, storing a variable into database and update it on every click, the variable is updated using javascript

Comment: Is there some limit user can click one post?

Comment: @Tpojka only the authenticated users can click on like button

Comment: You say can multiple times, but is limited that amount for one user for one post?

Comment: To rephrase, are you limiting user's ability to click same post infinite times?

Comment: user can click on like post until he rich the max which is 50 clicks

Comment: i can provide all the code using in Like.vue and the code that update variable using javascript but it'll be a long post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163522/discussion-between-a-bechir-and-tpojka).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set default value for `likes_count` to 50. Then, in your update method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    try {
        $userId = Auth::id();

        $like = Like::firstOrCreate([
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'post_id' => $id
        ]);

        if ((int)$like->likes_count < 1) {
            // user can not like this post anymore
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Like limit exceeded.']);
        }

        $like->decrement('likes_count');

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Post liked.']);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::info('Something went wrong liking post ' . $id . ' by ' . $userId . ': ' . $e->getMessage());
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Error.']);
    }


}
```

Don't forget to include classes (Request, Auth, App\Like, Log...).

Comment: "message" "Error"

Comment: Include `$e->getMessage()` instead of string 'Error.' and check what are you getting.

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: No response showing up, and nothing insert into database

Comment: You are getting "message" "Error." because of catch part of try catch block is executed. That means nothing in try part evaluated and consequently no DB insert either. If you used exact code, there should be something written in `storage/logs/laravel.log` file.

Comment: ok the output in log file is Error Local trying to get property of non-object, it gives an exception for another methode "showPost"

Comment: Start from there.

Comment: am sorry i was busy, Your code works greatly for increment or decrement the variable for likes already attached, but it doesn't attach new like when user like new post, i tried to add my first method but still no working Auth::user()->likes()->attach($post->id);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163559/discussion-between-a-bechir-and-tpojka).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of Reactions to items I've done before.  I'll offer you the model and stripped out logic in my Controller to save a reaction to help you figure it out.

This should give you a decent understanding of the table structure and the controller logic to handle it.

If you want more details on how the logic works, the please ask. Hope this helps.

**Models - Reaction and ReactionType.**

**The Reaction table** stores all reactions to things, it's a pivot table that stores

- user_id - The user who reacted/liked something
- The related table - The table where the object that user liked is from
- related table id - The references of what the user liked.... this is where I would find the person whose item was liked
- reaction_type_id - This is the reference to the type of reaction (see reaction type)

**ReactionType** - This stores the types of reactions people can have in your app:

- Reaction Name - The label used to tag the reaction (Like, dislike, hate, love, etc)
- description - Description of what the reaction means.
- Icon - What to present from an icon/image perspective in the view.

  ```
  class Reaction extends Model
  {
      protected $fillable = array('user_id', 'related_table', 'related_table_id', 'reaction_type_id');
      protected $table = 'reactions';
  }

  class ReactionType extends Model
  {
      protected $fillable = array('name', 'description', 'icon');
      protected $table = 'reaction_types';
  }
  ```

**Controller - This is what stores the reaction**  I have notes in the controller explaining it.

```
class ReactionController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Requests\ReactionRequest $request)
    {
        $reaction = array(
            'user_id' => $request->id, 
            'reaction_type_id' => $request->reaction_type_id, 
            'related_table' => $request->related_table, 
            'related_table_id' => $request->related_table_id );
        //Check to see if there's a record already.  You can only have one reaction per item. 
        $CheckInDB = Reaction::where('user_id', '=', $reaction['user_id'])
    ->where('related_table', '=', $reaction['related_table'])
    ->where('related_table_id', '=', $reaction['related_table_id'])->first();
    //If the reaction is in the database then update the type (did they change reaction? 
    if ($CheckInDB) {
        //If they sent the same exact reaction type that is already in the database, then 0 it out... This would indicate they unselected the reaction they provided.
        if($CheckInDB->reaction_type_id == $reaction['reaction_type_id'])   {
            $CheckInDB->reaction_type_id = 0;   
        }
        //Otherwise, update the reaction_type_id with the new reaction.
        else {
            $CheckInDB->reaction_type_id = $reaction['reaction_type_id'];   
        }
        //Update the reaction.
        $CheckInDB->save();
    }
    //If the user has never reacted to the item, then create a new record with that reaction.
    else {
        Reaction::create($reaction);
    }
    return back();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks to your reply @Dom, this is a good implementation, but it's not what i need, i want to let user like post more times, i have already implement like once and it's works, and i have a variable updated on every click in like btn, i just want to store that variable using vue js

Comment: The above model and controller will store likes for a particular post, which seemed to be your original question. Can you provide some details on what your current controller or save method looks like and why it isn’t working?

Comment: i have updated the question with more details, please take a look

Comment: @A.Bechir, Thanks, I just read your updated question.  It's missing one key element.  What does your store method (ie the method you use to store the click to the database) look like? If you can give me the store controller and dd($request->all()).  The like method you provided doesn't actually update a table on the database.  Also, what does the object look like where you retrieve the number of likes you have stored in the database for a particular post?

Comment: I can provide to you all the code and methods i used, but i don't if it's allowed here, to add the whole code in post

Comment: If I parse through your question, your true question is "how can i store a variable counter in likes_count column and update it on every click".  The code you provided doesn't give any insight into how you are attempting to store the data in your tables.  If you can show us how you are storing the data, you will get an answer and the question will be useful to the community. My answer provides you with how I handle reactions (Likes) in one of my applications.  I store them individually as a reaction by topic then aggregate them in a query to that table.

Comment: That's right, that is my question for now, first after when i ask the question i figure out how to implement like method, but like only once, and now i want to add storing method to store how many likes the post get, i will update the code with all my methods